# Lodash custom orderBy then by

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, lodash

I need to use lodash to implement a custom sort based on classification, then by creation time, with more recently created items with the same classification having a lower index in the array. I'm pretty sure I need to use `orderBy`, but I don't know how to add the date sorting part. This is what I have:

```
let sorted = _.orderBy(this.followed_requests, function(element){
 const rank = { "INCOMPLETE.NEW": 1,
                "INCOMPLETE.IN_PROGRESS":2,   
                "INCOMPLETE.LATER":3}
 return rank[element["status"]]})
```

I'd like my output to have something like:

```
sorted = [{status:"INCOMPLETE.NEW", created_at: "2021-05-14T14:48:00.000Z"},
          {status:"INCOMPLETE.NEW", created_at: "2021-05-13T14:48:00.000Z"},
          {status:"INCOMPLETE.IN_PROGRESS", created_at: "2021-05-14T14:48:00.000Z"},
          {status:"INCOMPLETE.IN_PROGRESS", created_at: "2021-05-13T14:48:00.000Z"},
          {status:"INCOMPLETE.LATER", created_at: "2021-05-14T14:48:00.000Z"},
          {status:"INCOMPLETE.NEW", created_at: "2021-05-13T14:48:00.000Z"} ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orderBy` accepts an array of functions and sort directions. There's multiple ways this could be implemented, but since both sort values require transformation this seems like a good option.

```js
const reqs = [
  { status: "INCOMPLETE.LATER", created_at: "2021-05-14T14:48:00.000Z" },
  { status: "INCOMPLETE.NEW", created_at: "2021-05-13T15:48:00.000Z" },
  { status: "INCOMPLETE.IN_PROGRESS", created_at: "2021-05-14T14:48:00.000Z" },
  { status: "INCOMPLETE.IN_PROGRESS", created_at: "2021-05-13T15:48:00.000Z" },
  { status: "INCOMPLETE.NEW", created_at: "2021-05-14T16:48:00.000Z" },
  { status: "INCOMPLETE.NEW", created_at: "2021-05-13T14:48:00.000Z" },
]

const rank = {
  "INCOMPLETE.NEW": 1,
  "INCOMPLETE.IN_PROGRESS": 2,
  "INCOMPLETE.LATER": 3,
}

let sorted = _.orderBy(reqs, [
  i => rank[i.status],
  i => new Date(i.created_at)
], ["asc", "asc"])

console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```